# Pandas.to_csv Causing Floats to Appear

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have created a program that takes in Excel sheets, modifies them with Pandas, and saves them to a CSV.

When I inspect the output CSV the columns are seen as ints, however when I upload to Oracle the columns become floats.

Some columns in the input excel are things such as "3" "4" "1" but other columns contain actual floats for monetary values. For this reason I can't cast onto the entire dataframe an as_type(int).

The excel sheets number in the hundreds, and have differing column names each month. So a columnwise application of as_type(int) will not work.

Code sample:

```
import pandas as pd
output_location = save_location + '.csv'

df_manipulation = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=None)
df_manipulation.to_excel(output_location, index = False)
```

Any ideas on how to keep the columns in question as ints?

Comment: Can you share some of the contents of the CSV?

Comment: 3, London, 4.53, UK is an example of column contents.

Comment: So the `3` is being converted to a float?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for read_excel(), specifically for the convert_float parameter, it mentions that Excel stores all numbers as floats internally.

If you want to convert the columns from float to int manually you can do:

```
df_manipulation['column_name'] = df_manipulation['column_name'].astype('int')
```

Alternatively, you can load the entire sheet with a specific datatype such as strings with:

```
df_manipulation = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=None, dtype = str)
```

Comment: I had thought of this solution initially, however this program is running through hundreds of different dataframes and column names are changed on a monthly basis. I am upvoting as this is a good solution, but not usable in this situation.

Do you know of a way to read_excel purely as strings?

Comment: @JosephPNardone _Do you know of a way to read_excel purely as strings?_ Use the `dtype` parameter.

Comment: Thank you AMC, I made the change and have to wait for testing. Tomorrow I will update if this solution works @CamelliaHilker, I have added this and accepted the solution.